# Magento Search and only include products in categories

Tags: magento-1.8, catalogsearch, search

Is it possible to set the native Magento search to only search products which are connected to a category?

Comment: Does the table join helps?  Or you are looking for non coding solution?

Answer (score 1):

Not out of the box. But you can set the product visibility in the admin to Catalog or Not Visible for the products you dont want to see in the search and will obtain the same result you are seeking without code.

Comment: Unfortunately this wont achieve the same results as I do want products to show in the search and in the catalogue. However I want products in the search to only be products which are connected to a category

Comment: You cannot have them show up in the search and not, computers are binary, set them to catalog visibility as suggested and that is the correct way. Unless there is something you are not explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can inner join table **catalog_category_product** to the search result collection I think.
Its structure as below:

```
+-------------+------------+----------+
| category_id | product_id | position |
+-------------+------------+----------+
|           3 |          5 |        1 |
|           4 |          6 |        1 |
|           3 |          7 |        1 |
+-------------+------------+----------+
```

Possible place is `app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer.php`,  method getProuctCollection();

Comment: How would I inner join that table?

Comment: Rewrite the block, get the collection select object, join the table. Not sure i understand the question.